# No hosted parallelism - Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

After reading through multiple similar questions regarding this issue, I opened up a ticket with Microsoft to grant free agent for private project and within 2-3 days they approved the request. Now I can see following agent under 'Agent Pools' -

[image: Agent Pools]

Now when I run my pipeline, I still get the error "No hosted parallelism has been purchased or granted. To request a free parallelism grant, please fill out the following form [https://aka.ms/azpipelines-parallelism-request"](https://aka.ms/azpipelines-parallelism-request%22)

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your project is private
[image]

Comment: Can you offer an explanation of why this would impact parallelism?